# Redirecionamento de URL pelo web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net, web.config

Preciso realizar um redirecionamento, da página `http://exemplo/comunicacao/` para a página `http://exemplo/caminho_novo/comunicacao`.

Estou realizando o seguinte no `web.config` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/caminho_novo/comunicacao$Q" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />    

   </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Até ai tudo bem, mas o problema é que o pessoal está chamando a página já com parâmetros preenchidos, e após o caminho `/comunicacao` eu tenho um `asp` chamado `exibe.asp` que recebe parâmetros para exibir o conteúdo.

Fazendo desse modo como está configurado no `web.config`, a `url` vem montada da seguinte maneira : 
`exemplo/caminho_novo/comunicacao/?id=136923/exibe.asp`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, o parâmetro está vindo antes da página `asp`, o certo seria :

`exemplo/caminho_novo/comunicacao/exibe.asp?id=136923`

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou adicionar o `$V`, que é o caminho da url com página antes do `$Q` que é a `querystring`, o `exactDestination="true"`, que informa que será um caminho absoluto e não relativo:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" 
              destination="/caminho_novo/comunicacao$V$Q" 
              exactDestination="true"
              httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
```

Comment: Ricardo funcionou! Só foi preciso usar `httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/presencial$V$Q" 
        exactDestination="true"
       httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />` O que não entendi muito bem foi o uso do `exactDestination="true"`.

Answer (score 1):

O $Q apenas introduz a querystring, não faço ideia quem está a introduzir o exibe.asp à frente de tudo.
Existem várias variáveis que podes usar para construir o teu URL com o HttpRedirect como diz na página de referência da Microsoft.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525695%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Dá-me ideias que estás a mandar colocar o $Q antes do nome da página.

> Passes the requested URL, without the server name and without any
>   parameters. To include parameters, use the $P or $Q variable with the
>   $V variable.

Experimenta com o exemplo que lá vem na documentação, tal qual:
/caminho_novo/comunicacao$S$Q

Comment: Obrigado, me serviu também!